# why do I get "Error:(57, 21) error: reached end of file while parsing"

Tags: java, android

This is the error I get

> Error:(57, 21) error: reached end of file while parsing

while using this code

```
package com.bilalbenzine.hotel;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Thing;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

import io.realm.Realm;

/**
 * Created by hmito on 04/04/2017.
 */

public class add_hotel extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_hotel);

        final EditText name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name_hotel);
        final EditText place=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.place_hotel);
        final EditText stars=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.stars);
        final EditText description=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.description);

        final Button addhotel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_add_hotel);
        addhotel.hasOnClickListeners(new View.OnClickListener(){

       @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
           hotel hotel = new hotel();
           hotel.setName_hotel(name.getText().toString());
           hotel.setName_hotel(place.getText().toString());
           hotel.setName_hotel(stars.getText().toString());
           hotel.setName_hotel(description.getText().toString());

           Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
           realm.beginTransaction();
           realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(hotel);
           realm.commitTransaction();


           Toast.makeText(add_hotel.this, "The hotel has been successfully added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Fix your spacing and your problem will be obvious-  your {} and () pairs aren't matching.

Comment: You may use Android Studio to format your code. Please do that before posting your question

Comment: the number is matching

Comment: Also, `hasOnClickListeners` isn't a method, is it?

Comment: I have not found the solution yet

Comment: You use `setOnClickListener` with buttons

Comment: where !! really help me im a biginner

Comment: thank you very much . The problem has been solved

Answer (score 0):

You miss a pair {}.
Please use following code.

```
package com.bilalbenzine.hotel;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Thing;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

import io.realm.Realm;

/**
 * Created by hmito on 04/04/2017.
 */

public class add_hotel extends AppCompatActivity 
{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_hotel);

        final EditText name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name_hotel);
        final EditText place=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.place_hotel);
        final EditText stars=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.stars);
        final EditText description=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.description);

        final Button addhotel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_add_hotel);
        addhotel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                hotel hotel = new hotel();
                hotel.setName_hotel(name.getText().toString());
                hotel.setName_hotel(place.getText().toString());
                hotel.setName_hotel(stars.getText().toString());
                hotel.setName_hotel(description.getText().toString());

                Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                realm.beginTransaction();
                realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(hotel);
                realm.commitTransaction();


                Toast.makeText(add_hotel.this, "The hotel has been successfully added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            }
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem remains,,,!

Comment: @ZizouMadrid you also use hasOnClickListeners but it may be setOnClickListener. Check my answer where i use setOnClickListener instead of hasOnClickListeners.

Answer (score 0):

1.

`hasOnClickListeners` is not `setOnClickListener`.

2.

> “Error:(57, 21) error: reached end of file while parsing”

You're missing a closing bracket "`}`" somewhere in your code.

Android studio underlines errors, hover over red underlined code and follow the advice.

Comment: While at it follow Java and android naming conventions. Classes follow `UpperCamelCase` style and activities should end in `Activity`. In your example it would be `AddHotelActivity`. It makes the code so much more readable.

Comment: @ZizouMadrid Welcome to StackOverflow, please read [about accepting answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).